# Map_server could not open /home/test_map.yaml

Tags: navigation, kinect, amcl-demo.launch, ros-kinetic, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using a package called Chefbot, which has packages to run a differential drive autonomously using SLAM.
However when I run the command: `roslaunch chefbot_bringup amcl_demo.launch map_file:=/home/test_map.yaml`

I get an error: `[ERROR] [1553483186.539747153]: Map_server could not open /home/test_map.yaml.`
I read previous questions about the same, and for most of them the problem was solved by adding a '/' before the home directory. But I still get this error.
I've checked that the map test_map exists.
Please help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/319378/map_server-could-not-open-/home/test_map.yaml./) by [parzival](https://answers.ros.org/users/35453/parzival/) on ROS Answers with karma: 463 on 2019-03-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) on 2019-03-25**:
Hi,

Can you please edit the question with the output of

```
ls -l /home/test_map.yaml
```

**Comment by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) on 2019-03-25**:
Because ideally the path should be something like

```
/home/user_name/test_map.yaml
```

**Comment by [parzival](https://answers.ros.org/users/35453/parzival/) on 2019-03-25**:
Thanks a lot! That worked.

**Comment by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) on 2019-03-26**:
No prob.
You should add how you solved the problem as an answer, accept it and close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The path should be `/home/username/map.yaml` and not `/home/map.yaml`.

Also make sure there's a `'/'` before `home`.

This should do the job.

---

Originally posted by [parzival](https://answers.ros.org/users/35453/parzival/) with karma: 463 on 2019-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0